# How to pop off first string of a QString?

Tags: c++, qt, parsing, qstring

For example, my `QString` is `"12  1,2 3,4"` and I want to pop off `"12"` and then maybe trim off the leading whitespace so that it becomes `" 1,2 3,4"`

This is part of reading from an input file.

```
QFile input_file("path/to/testfile.txt");

if (!input_file.exists()) {
  dbg << "File does NOT exist" << endl;
  exit(1);
}

if (!input_file.open(QFile::ReadOnly)) {
  exit(2);
}

QDataStream input_stream(&input_file);
while (!input_file.atEnd()) {
  QString line = input_stream.readLine();
  // how do I parse off that first number?
```

Comment: Use a string stream? On second thought, it looks like `QDataStream` works the same way.

Comment: @chris I'm not very familiar, but it looks like `QDataStream` expects binary data, not text.

Comment: @DrewDormann, Ah, so it would seem. I just saw all of those overloads of `operator>>`. That's what I get for not being familiar with Qt.

Comment: Perhaps http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qstring.html#split is what you can use...

Comment: @JeremyFriesner That may well be the best choice.  It's not clear from the question what's to be done with the remainder of the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like [`QTextStream`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtextstream.html) would do the job, where your comment currently is.

`QTextStream` seems to be the QT equivalent of `std::istringstream`, designed to parse text that's separated by whitespace.

```
QTextStream text_stream( &line );
QString that_first_numer;

text_stream >> that_first_number;  // Read text up to whitespace
line = text_stream.read_line();    // Copy the remaining text back to line.
```

Comment: "This class is part of the Qt 3 support library. It is provided to keep old source code working. We strongly advise against using it in new code"  Otherwise that looks like what i need soooo soooo badly.  I'm using Qt 5.2 :(

Comment: @tarabyte I have modified the answer to be more friendly to Qt4. `QTextIStream` and `QTextOStream` [have been rolled into `QTextStream`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/porting4.html#qtextistream) for Qt4.

Comment: @tarabyte it looks like you're now asking new questions.  I'd recommend posting a new question if your current question isn't the same anymore.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can split the string into substrings seperated by any character :

```
QStringList tokens= line.split(" ",QString::SkipEmptyParts);
```

Now the first number can be accessed by `tokens[0]`.

Removing the first element and trimming the string is simply like :

```
line.remove(0,tokens[0].length()).trimmed();
```